# Как скачать файл на Flask

Tags: python, flask

Вроде все правильно, но ничего не скачивается.

Вот мой метод

```
@admin.route('/download_doc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_doc():
    doc_id = request.json['id']
    doc = Doc.query.filter(Doc.id==doc_id).first()
    filename = doc.filename
    uploads = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

Но почему-то ошибка 404 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смущает, то что когда я пишу для print для uploads, то выдается следующий путь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эти фокусы со слешами - прикол WIndows. 
У вас везде в приложении, скорее всего, указан слеш такой '/', а винда везде юзает такой '\'. 
Не знаю какой из них прямой. а какой обратный.
У товарища было что-то подобное на винде.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать os.path.normpath(). Эта функция нормализует путь в соответствии с операционной системой.

```
>>> path_a = "D:\Desktop\test"
>>> path_b = 'static/doc'

>>> uploads = os.path.join(path_a, path_b)
'D:\\Desktop\test\\static/doc'

>>> norm_uploads = os.path.normpath(uploads)
'D:\\Desktop\test\\static\\doc'
```

Еще возможно, что адреса admin\download_doc действительно не существует. Если admin - блюпринт, проверьте указали ли вы для него префикс при регистрации:

```
app.register_blueprint(admin , url_prefix='/admin ')
```